# where does the input from the pressed keys when on the desktop/homescreen goto/saved at what buffer?

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, hotkeys, keylogger

how to capture the text input from the keyboard when not in any writing mode like in notepad or word i.e just on idle desktop and we randomly press keyboard buttons?

Comment: So you want a keylogger?

Comment: kind of a keylogger.. but does a keylogger store every key that is pressed even whn on desktop?

Comment: Well it would depend on the exact software, but as I understand it,  the whole purpose of a keylogger is to record every single keypress that occurs while it runs, no matter what else is or isn't running.

Answer (score 0):

In programming its called a "keyboard hook" (look here for more information. It can be implemented in a number of ways, in a number of languages, but that is what you talking about.